# Visual Studio 2010 icon displays UAC shield

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, icons, uac

I've just installed Visual Studio 2010 on my home computer and as pictured below, the icon displays with the UAC shield.

[image]

This is of course not an issue, but is this normal behaviour on an administrator account with UAC turned off? I don't recall having this on my work machine.

Comment: You probably don't have it at work because you don't need admin privileges to run it at work. I'd first turn UAC on, and then make VS run as regular user (unless you're debugging processes running with administrative privileges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct behavior as recommended by Microsoft's User Account Control Guidlines.  The relevant part is under the "[UAC shield icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511445.aspx#shieldIcon)" guidelines section and states:

> Display the UAC shield even if User Account Control has been turned
>   off or the user is using the Built-in Administrator account.
>   Consistently displaying the UAC shield is easier to program, and
>   provides users with information about the nature of the task.

You can read the whole document here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511445.aspx.